# Eclipse is not generating the exe file even after build

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, exe, linker-errors

I have never had this problem while working on eclipse. I have been working on this particular project for a while and recently eclipse froze while building the project(it has happened before) and i had to kill the eclipse process... When i restarted eclipse, the exe file did not exist in the file system (in my Debug Folder) and when i Rebuild, it still does not get generated even though it says : "Build Finished (took 103 ms)" ... which is way faster than  the normal build time of my project.

Edit 1:
BTW i did a project clean but it didn't help.
Also i tried closing and reopening eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Funny! I myself found the problem, though i don't understand it!

I closed eclipse and found that there was a process still running called : "g++.exe" in my process list in "Windows Task manager" which i knew shouldn't be running with eclipse closed! So i simply killed it and reopened eclipse, and the problem was solved!

Also look for processes like:

- starter.exe
- gcc.exe
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all the object files (with a build clean) and then do a rebuild.

Comment: Very Funny! I myself found the problem, though i don't understand it!

I closed eclipse and found that there was a process still running called : "g++.exe" in my process list in "Windows Task manager" which i knew shouldn't be running with eclipse closed! So i simply killed it and reopened eclipse, and the problem was solved! And BTW i did do a clean (i forgot to mention in the question) but it didn't help...)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the antivirus software (Avast) was automatically deleting the .exe file, and I had to disable it for running my program.